# Detect UIControlEventTouchDown on UITabBarItem

Tags: uitabbar, uicontrol, uicontrolevents

I would like to set the selected image of a tabbar as soon as the user touches the UITabBarItem.

Currently there is a small delay before the highlight appears. Is there a way to get UIControlEvents at a UITabBarItem level ?